# barra vertical en menú css , como desaparecer la primera y ultima barra?

Tags: css, menu

Hola estoy aprendiendo css y quisiera eliminar la barra vertical que sale al comienzo de "Home" y la que esta al comienzo de "Donate" como podría hacer eso, ? alguna idea por favor, gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
 <ul className="nav-links">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#home">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#research">Research Institute Projects</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#press">Press</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#volunteer">Volunteer</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a className="elipse" href="#donate">Donate</a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
```

```css
 #menu ul li {
        list-style-type: none;
        display: inline;
        border-left: 2px solid black;
        height: 500px;

    }
```

Comment: Usa las pseudo-clases para primer y último hijo: `#menu ul li:first-child, #menu ul li:last-child{ border-left: none;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrega en número al selector `nth-child` con el siguiente css, suponiendo que es el cuarto elemento

```css
#menu ul li:nth-child(4){
border: none
}
```

O suponiendo que siempre va a ser el último `li`

```css
#menu ul li:last-child{
border:none
}
```

Comment: gracias Dav, me funciono